# How do I add key / value pairs to a global variable in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, global-variables

I've got a program that add's a bunch of Div's to a page.  I have a bunch of extra 'data-' attributes added to the divs that I later want to include in a global variable.

I basically want to set something up like this:

```
$.scoreArray = {
    scores: [],
    labels: []
};
$(".word").each(function (i) {
    $.scoreArray.labels.label = $(this).attr("data-label");
    $.scoreArray.labels.x = $(this).attr("data-x");
}
...
```

but I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'label' of undefined`

I've tried putting .label and .x as ["label"] and ["x"] but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do - create an array of objects scoreArray.labels with one entry for each word? Or do you only want to store the last word found in a single labels object? If you make labels `{}` not `[]` then it should work, but may not be what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: I think I see what you want to do.  You want the arrays to contain a bunch of objects, one for each word, which contain the attributes you're collecting.  So you want something like:

```
$.scoreArray = {
    scores: [],
    labels: []
};
$(".word").each(function (i) {
    newLabel = {};
    newLabel.label = $(this).attr("data-label");
    newLabel.x = $(this).attr("data-x");
    $.scoreArray.labels.push(newLabel);
}
```

However, the error you're seeing sounds like the "global" variable you created isn't being found in the scope you're in.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: I think the OP *does* want arrays, but wants to push objects into them.

Comment: That wouldn't be the source of the Error OP is getting. Javascript won't complain when adding named properties to an Array.

Comment: That is just a piece of the code, but the above works for what I want it to do (i think).  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$.scoreArray.labels` is `undefined` when you try to access it.

Make sure it is defined *before* you try to add items to it.

As a side note, others are correct that if you're going to use named properties, you should use an object instead of an Array.

If you wanted an array of objects, do this:

```
$.scoreArray = {
    scores: [],
    labels: []
};
$(".word").each(function (i) {
    $.scoreArray.labels[ i ] = {};
    $.scoreArray.labels[ i ].label = $(this).attr("data-label");
    $.scoreArray.labels[ i ].x = $(this).attr("data-x");
}
```

or this:

```
$.scoreArray = {
    scores: [],
    labels: []
};
$(".word").each(function (i) {
    $.scoreArray.labels[ i ] = {label: $(this).attr("data-label"),
                                    x: $(this).attr("data-lx")
                               };
}
```

or perhaps an even better solution would be to use `.map()`. This (and the other solutions) assume you're not adding to an existing Array.

```
$.scoreArray.labels = $(".word").map(function (i) {
     return {label: $(this).attr("data-label"),
                 x: $(this).attr("data-lx")
            };
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you'd be better with an array of objects rather than an object with two arrays as it looks like a score should be kept tied with the label.

```
// are you sure you want to add this as a property on the jQuery object?
var $.scoreArray = $.map($('.word') , function(elem) { 
                       var self = $(elem);
                       return { score : self.attr("data-x"),
                                label : self.attr("data-label") };
                   });

// $.scoreArray will be an array of objects, each with a score and label property
```